# "ImportError: No module named" but I already typed "pip install"

Tags: python, import, pip, installation, traceback

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to run some scripts in Python for my university classes.
I had to install MacPorts but I installed some Python versions before...
My script has this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/matteo/Dropbox/tesi_magistrale/lmgc90_user/build")
import telepot
import time
from pprint import pprint
```

I used the `sys.path.append` because I need that folder if I want to use a software for my thesis.
When I run the script I have:

```
MacBook-Pro-di-Matteo-2:telegram matteo$ python bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 15, in <module>
    import telepot
ImportError: No module named telepot
```

But I typed:

```
MacBook-Pro-di-Matteo-2:telegram matteo$ pip install telepot
Requirement already satisfied: telepot in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/telepot-12.3-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.9.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from telepot)
```

If I type:

```
MacBook-Pro-di-Matteo-2:telegram matteo$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python

MacBook-Pro-di-Matteo-2:telegram matteo$ which -a python
/opt/local/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python

MacBook-Pro-di-Matteo-2:telegram matteo$ which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip

MacBook-Pro-di-Matteo-2:telegram matteo$ which -a pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

My .bash_profile has these lines:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

##
# Your previous /Users/matteo/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/matteo/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2017-09-12_at_16:05:41
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2017-09-12_at_16:05:41: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

I use a Mac with Yosemite 10.10.4. I have this problem with "telepot" package and all the others, like panda3d, matplotlib etc.
Thank you!

Comment: Obviously, you have imported `telepot` to a wrong python installation.

Comment: @AliHashemi Thank you for your reply. Do you have any suggestions to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `pip` using a different python executable then `python` command invoked

You could [re-install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) with `python get-pip.py`, newly installed pip bin will be aligned with python executable in use, then install your packages, they should work.

But I suggest you clean up your local python installations and `$PATH` setting afterward.

Comment: Thank you. I typed `pip uninstall pip` and then `python get-pip.py` but I have some errors and finally:
`OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip' `

Comment: uninstall is not necessary, though you could try run commands again with sudo

Comment: It says `Successfully installed pip-9.0.1 wheel-0.30.0` but if I run the script I have:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Plot_Solver_Distribution_Forces.py", line 11, in <module>
    import Image
ImportError: No module named Image`

Comment: alll your packages reinstalled?

Comment: In this case I typed `pip uninstall Image` and then `pip install Image` but still this error...

Comment: Sorry but could you explain exactly what to do? :) Sorry but I'm totally new with this

Comment: your question listed your environment status, plz update it with current status, I need more info to help you